# Hard pigeonhole principle problem.

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

Prove that having 100 whole numbers, one can choose 15 of them so that the difference of any two is divisible by 7.

Comment: Put two numbers in the same pigeonhole if they have the same remainder on division by $7$. So there are $7$ pigeonholes. If each had $\le 14$ numbers, then the total number of numbers would be $\le 98$.